# RPG inventory class for carrying & trading with npc's

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, selecteditem, inventory

My goal is to make an item & inventory system like they have in the game called Runescape for my single player iPhone RPG game, with SpriteKit. They have a lot of items, which is what I want to implement: such as wood, bread, different types of catchable fish. They also have a 4x7 inventory (4 columns & 7 rows) where items are re-arrangeable with the mouse by clicking & dragging. So when you trade with an NPC shopkeeper, you have your inventory & theirs open up & you commence trading by dragging & dropping. From my end, world creation and main character & NPC placement is complete. The touch controls of the main character are also complete. However, now I have no idea how to tackle this mountain of a problem with the inventory & items. The tid-bits of scattered information I could find on the internet makes me panic even more, due to a lack of any tutorial on the matter - I don't know where to begin or what questions to ask. I'm a novice programmer. Could someone recommend some form of tutorial? If non exist for Objective-C then for any other programming language would do I guess. As long as I can look at the code. At which point I'll try to figure something out. Thank you in advance to anyone with any form of solution.

P.S. Should I begin learning Core Data for the database? Should begin learning how to save things to plists?

Comment: To start, try breaking your problem down into smaller steps (or this question might get closed as too broad). You need a system to drag and drop sprites, a data model to store different types and quantities of item and actual item classes. Try just making an item class, what does it need, a sprite, an amount of space to take up, a value etc. There is another excellent stack exchange site called http://gamedev.stackexchange.com which may better answer the non programming parts of your question, item data models etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your question isn't very clear and hard to answer. I can say that you should learn Core Data if you wish to have persistence between app launches especially with the scope of your project.

My recommendation is attack this problem in two parts. First attack storing picking up and stacking items and putting them into an Array of items for your character. This should be more of a "model" attack to the problem. After you have that working and items are being added I would then attack the SpriteKit or "view" aspect of the issue.

I have actually been working on a similar thing and you can see my GitHub for the project [here](https://github.com/Urthstripe29/Old-Frank/tree/0.0.1). Maybe you will find something there you can use and implement it in your game.

Again sorry if it doesn't directly answer your question but at least it might get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I'm going to try your way. Thank you for the github link.

Comment: Awesome and glad it helps. I would mark this as answered if it answered your question.

Comment: When I click the green arrow, does that mean the question has been answered?

Comment: Yup it is marked accepted.

Comment: @SkylerLauren I am trying to understand how your SMDCoreDataHelper and ItemManager work...So, if I understand well ItemManager using a sqllite file to operate with items. But what is the purpose of using SMDCoreDataHelper ?  Is there any link where are I can read more about this project of yours ? Thanks !

Comment: @Whirlwind SMDCoreDataHelper (CoreData) is for saving my map data and game state. ItemManager and the sqlite file is a static table I am using to store all of my item information. There is no link I have that goes into depth on how I am doing what, but have been debating adding that to my site as I go because I thought it a fun idea for others to learn and/or contribute. Any further questions feel free to email me at skyler@skymistdevelopment.com